# Over 243,000 views in 3 days?

Tags: discussion, views

I can see some other websites [linking to this](http://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F231273%2Fwhat-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for+-site%3Asuperuser.com), but is [this >243k view count](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for) in just 3 days really correct...?

[image: 243k views according to front page]

[image: Viewed 243,229 times times according to side bar]

Comment: Given which question you're showing, how it was linked on several places including a tweet from Jeff... yes, that looks about right.

Comment: Okay, then we need more questions like that. Maybe I should change this question into "More ideas for questions like this?", to keep Super User alive!

Comment: While... amusing, to put it lightly... that question does have one real good thing going for it as far as being a popular and highly viewed question - it's *actually a question*. So bravo enough for that.

Comment: Hah I remember seeing that question just when it had ~200 views... my how it has grown.  Makes my case about having external links to crazy questions even stronger.  :)

Comment: I still think it's slightly ridiculous - only 2 of the 50 top votes questions on SO have had more than that amount of views, and most were only accumulated over two years: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: @Grace, more fun facts: it was actually an off topic question on Stack Overflow first! Bravo for migration too!

Comment: Wow, viewed 222,686 times only 15 minutes later. It's just starting! Love to see some statistics later on! Hopefully the team can add some well-paying advertising in time!

Comment: @Arjan: Your question might just add significantly to the view count of that one.

Comment: @JP19, *this* very question has been viewed 43 times now. No, that does not account for over 1,000 new views in 30 minutes.

Comment: Hmm, I think I should ask the question "What are the letters A and B used for" over at English Language and Usage, where the most popular question *ever* [hasn't even reached 5,000 views](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/do-most-languages-need-more-space-than-english). Brb.

Comment: Or ask Jeff [to tweet](http://topsy.com/superuser.com/questions/231273/for-what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for) about a random other question, @Reg :-)

Comment: Yes @Arjan, they are correct, especially Reddit caused a very large peak in the traffic yesterday

Comment: Ah, @Ivo, any chance you know of some figures, and know if you can publish those?

Comment: I don't know if I can publish those, but I'll get back to you if I do @Arjan And when will you ever learn to use chat?

Comment: Heej, my self-built computer also still has a floppy drive! But my upcoming upgrade to Sandy Bridge is going to kill it :-P @Arjan

Comment: I just figured that if, for some reason, the team does not want to show the statistics, then collecting some (late) view counts ourselves might not be too nice either. Deleted my answer; hoping for whatever @Ivo or the team can show — but really just out of curiosity.

Comment: Perhaps @JeffAtwood can shine a light on what to do!

Comment: it was also tweeted by @Smashingmag, who has over 300k followers.

Comment: Rapid answers of similar ramble kicked the whole question to CW at 15. @ivo

Comment: can't you (stack staff) create a new badge for such a score ? (traffic jam maker?)

Comment: @AUS we already have the Famous Question gold badge.

Comment: I feel like I've won the lotto. I never had thought that this question would gain 250+ views overnight. especially since I've asked it 10 days ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So to show the curious among you what an impact a viral post being shared on social media can have (points @Arjan):

[image]

The page views more than doubled that day and we even got an additional 200 new users (on top of our normal growth)

Who should we thank for this network effect? Well the next short list speaks for itself:
[image]

Reddit is the clear winner, followed with a still nice amounts by Hacker News, Facebook, Twitter, Stumbleupon and Fark.com. Quite unexpected, even the Pirate Bay sent us a decent amount of traffic that day!

So there you have it: the Social Network effect! Therefore, feel free to make good use of the new Twitter streams, who knows perhaps you question will get picked up too!

Comment: Teh 3 Googles combined are about 45K

Comment: Could be, but note that these referrals are for the whole site not just that one question

Answer (score 14):

Well, let's have some fun collecting the stats for this question ourselves.

- [bit.ly stats](http://bit.ly/fntOIR+): 14.1k clicks
- [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2095628): 400 points, 260 comments
- [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/f0tpe/do_you_feel_old_for_knowing_the_answer_to_this/): 5400 total votes, 1100 comments
- [twitter](http://topsy.com/superuser.com/questions/231273/for-what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for): 1200 tweets

Numbers are rounded, because they'll change rapidly anyway. Be sure to add to this list if you have any other link stats.

Answer (score 9):

If you're asking why -- the question is popular because it is an obvious sign of the passing times :)

"What's a floppy disk anyway?"

Comment: I once helped someone who got their floppy stuck in their zip.  We got it out, and the zip was fine, but I'm told the floppy was never the same again...