# How come this question has 200+ kviews?

Tags: support, specific-question, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Over 243,000 views in 3 days?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1893/over-243-000-views-in-3-days)

[What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)

The view count of this question is the highest to be found on any stackexchange question, how is that possible, it's barely two weeks old...

Comment: Not a bug @Sander :-) Super User really is that awesome